# Difficulties in replacing the original menu items (subcategories) links in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, elementor

I'm working on an e-commerce website (built with Elementor) and there's an all category dropdown menu with subcategories, but I'm having difficulties changing the original links of the subcategories. The Phones and Tablets subcat is pointing to the url of medical items, which is placed as Orginal, which is not meant to be. I've tried several means changing it but I can't find any URL to make change. Please can anyone help me with this issue. The website is https://waziri.ng[image: the backend page][image: the frontend page]

I tried using the Uber setting but I can't find any input that relates to the "Original" url input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can change the link, you should instead try replacing the category.

What the element you are trying to edit represents is the Medical-items-category "object". All you can change is te label on the link.

The benefit of this is, that if you change the URL of the Category "Medical items", your link in the menu still works.

---

What you probably want to do is:

- remove the current item.
- Look up "Phones and Tablets" in de column just to the left.
- Add that item to the menu and drag it in place.